# Loss of non ascii characters from QString to char *

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8

I have a QString with non ascii characters . I am passing this QString to another process . However when I debug the receiving process the argv arguments do not receive a correct string that was intended from the source . My pseudo code would be

```
process.start( proc, QStringList() << "-a" <<param );
        process.waitForFinished(m_timeout);
```

Here param is the QString that contains the non ascii text

Comment: Which OS is this? Encoding of process parameters typically depends on your environment and the application in question.

Comment: windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Does the program accept non-ASCII parameters outside of Qt? Try running proc -a "....." in a `cmd` window. If that works, you can try in Qt with `process.setNativeArguments()`.

Comment: even thru command prompt if i pass the string ,in the debugger of the process  I do not get the correct characters

Comment: Then the problem is on the receiving application. You should make a new question about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code

```
LPWSTR *szArglist;
int argC;
szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(),&argC);
if(NULL==szArglist) {
          throw;
}
QString  qstrConvertFile = QString::fromUtf16((const ushort*)(szArglist[4]));
```